# Why does 022 - 2 equal 16 in Java?

Tags: java, int

Why does 022 - 2 equal 16?

```
int q = 022 - 2;
```

And then `System.out.println(q);` statement shows `16`

Comment: Octal numbers: integer like number literals that start with  with `0` are base 8. Ah, and now I've found the duplicate question.

Comment: 022 (base 8) = 18  (base 10)

Comment: ^ that would be base 8 :)

Comment: corrected - typo (octal was mapped to 16 temporarily in mind ? )